# Synergy compatibilty

Tags: macos, ubuntu, synergy

I want to run synergy on my Mac (client) and Ubuntu (server). I get errors from the Mac that it is not compatible with the synergy 1.3 on the server. I want to find out if synergy 1.5 and 1.7 are compatible?. Does compatibilty mean exactly the same versions on both system?

Comment: Best to run the same version.

Answer (score 1):

If you use different versions of Synergy running on different machines, as long as Synergy internal protocol is the same, Synergy would be connected. The way to check is setting debug level to Debug1 and check the log window for "created proxy for client "screenname" version 1.x". Generally the best solution is using the same version of Synergy on all machines.

Another fact is OS compatibility. For the latest release, 1.8.7, it supports from 10.9 to 10.12 on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have it working on a Ubuntu (server) and a Windows 7 (client). It was very smooth, until the day the updates came, and it took me a lot of time to get it running again. Basically, you should have the same version running on both machines; or, if my memory doesn´t fail, the server should be at least the highest version.

Answer (score -1):

I, too, have the problem. My main squeeze, Ubuntu Box, runs a slightly different version than my newly installed Q4OS. My laptop, in either Fedora or Win 7 cooperates nicely. AS does the XP tower on my right. The Ubuntu says it's upgraded to newest. Liar. When Q4OS is booted on the the white tower on the right, it shows a newer version and complains.  The other versions aren't exact matches either. If the dependencies check we might try a downloaded "deb" package or use a repository that has that version. Version mismatches and dependencies scare me. Without knowing which matches are close, we're shooting in the dark. Paying the ten bucks is appealing right now.
https://github.com/synergy/synergy/releases?after=1.6.1
Looks like a good chance here. We may have "make" "install" to recompile.
Good luck. Synergy is worth it.
I'm not sure if Q4OS is worth this hassle.